# How to get only public IP addresses in java

Tags: java

I saw some answers about this question here in stackoverflow. The main difference of my code is that it is obtaining only the public IP addresses, by doing continue either when the loopback interface or an IP for point-to-point connection is found.

Obs: I'm comparing with the localhost's IP because as I've VirtualBox, the localhost was the IP used to communicate with that machine. I'm trying to understand why. The method returns a String but it could easily be the InetAddress. Feedback is always wellcome. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
private String getPublicIpAddress() {
    String res = null;
    try {
        String localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
            if(ni.isLoopback())
                continue;
            if(ni.isPointToPoint())
                continue;
            Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = ni.getInetAddresses();
            while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress address = (InetAddress) addresses.nextElement();
                if(address instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    String ip = address.getHostAddress();
                    if(!ip.equals(localhost))
                        System.out.println((res = ip));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You should also test the Inet4Addr objects to see if they are "site local", "link local" and a few other things.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html

Comment: Ok.
I didn't look at that those methods, but it might be the best way to do all the comparisons.
Thanks Stephen!